# Code Blocks won't recognize the header for the class it wrote?

Tags: c++, class, header, codeblocks

I'm currently writing a small class to implement the Smith-Waterman algorithm in C++ in Code Blocks 10.05 on Ubuntu 11.10, although I ran into the exact same problem on CodeBlocks on Windows, I added a class with the new class option and it seemed to generate valid .h and .cpp files.

But when I try to compile in `smithwaterman.cpp` it gives me an error on the line it wrote that `#include "smithwaterman.h"` saying it can't find the file.

I can clearly see the file in the project at `include/smithwaterman.h` and I've tried to put the include/ but it doesn't help, if I included it with it's full path then it sees it but it seems like a very inelegant solution and right after that CodeBlocks blocked the .h file and I couldn't edit it.

Also after finishing that dialog box which lets me define the class it asked me if I want to include it in both bin and debug and I said yes.

Has anyone encountered this sort of problem before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this link. It helped me out a lot with the same problem.

http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/codeblocks-failed-to-find-the-header-file/

Make sure when you add a folder to the search directory that the header and implementation file that you wish to include are in that folder, i.e. not in a folder within that folder.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

should go to here in toolbar:
Project/Build Options/search directories
now using the address of "include" folder,where headers are put usually there,add it.
This way a header can be included.

```
   #include "header.h"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been trying to figure out how to point to a specific folder and all I could find is suggestions to include the entire path to the directory in my #include line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i guess all i could do is to save and close the project and then re open it again and it worked fine, but i guess there should be a faster way to fix this issue. any way try what I've told you if you're desperate :)